# ng-repeat not loading data after html has been compiled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that copies a bit of html that includes a controller and an ng-repeat.  I compile the html and stick it into the dom.  I can see that the new html is picking up the scope of the newly compiled controller but ng-repeat will not work if the data is loaded async.

I have created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jCjW26PCwlmKVTohja0s?p=preview which shows the problem that I'm having.

index.html

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="put-compiled-data-in-here" compile-html>
        <!-- copied html goes in here -->
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="CopiedController" class="copy blue">
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="p in projects">
            <h1>{{p.name}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('CopiedController', function($scope, slowService){
   $scope.projects = slowService.loadSlowData();
   $scope.name = "Inside Copied Controller";
 });
```

Directive that copies and compiles the html

```
app.directive('compileHtml', function ($compile, $rootScope, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            var html = jQuery('.copy').clone().removeClass('.blue').addClass('.pink');
            var el = angular.element(html);
            ele.append(el);
            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
        }
     };
});
```

Slow service (aka ajax):

```
app.service('slowService', function($timeout) {
    this.loadSlowData = function() {
        return $timeout(function() {
          return [{name:"Part 2a"},
                 {name:"Part 2b" } ]
          }, 300);
     };    
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want the copied section to load the data again which is what it looks like you're trying to do? Or do you just want to display the same data in two different places in the page? If the latter then you should put the data in scope such that both things can see it. Perhaps with a shared service.

Comment: what's the point of manipulating class on a clone.... then only using it's inner html? Use `ng-class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check

```
    http://plnkr.co/edit/l7o5EFC3863ZI4cxvuos?p=preview
```

Change the following

```
    <div ng-controller="CopiedController" class="put-compiled-data-in-here" compile-html>




    app.directive('compileHtml', function($compile, $rootScope, $parse) {
        return {
            template: $('.copy').html(),
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
                // var html = jQuery('.copy').clone().removeClass('.blue').addClass('.pink');
                // var el = angular.element(html);
                // ele.append(el);
                // $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                ele.removeClass('blue').addClass('pink');
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: this worked thank you.  Could you explain why this worked and my attempt didn't work as I thought compiling in the link phase would have done the same thing.

Comment: It's not the compiling in the link phase not working. It's just when you get $('.copy'), the jQuery object you get is not the rendered one.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the '.' from removeClass and addClass operators

```
var html = jQuery('.copy').clone().removeClass('blue').addClass('pink');
```

[image]